# Loop over hour:minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm with Rails 4:

I need to make a loop in a table to display time of the day as title of column, like that

8:00 | 8:30 | 9:00 .... 20:00 | 20:30 | 21:00

Do you have any idea how to define the loop? 
I've try complicated things with step() but meaby I have miss a easy way using Time?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand, you need to display time slots of the day? like: 00:00| 00:30| 01:00|01:30....|23:00|23:30|??

Comment: yes exactly, in my <th> tag.

Comment: I answered this question once before here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287275/171183 -- does this help?

Comment: Seem helpful. Thanks. What to do? I remove the my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Rails [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) like this (for n steps you want)

```
startdate = DateTime.new(2001,2,3) 
interval = 30
formatstr = '%H:%M'
(0..n).map{|offset| startdate + (offset * interval).minutes }
      .map{|date| date.strftime(formatstr)}
```

Comment: Ok, seem nice! Thanks