# Iterate over Time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on business analytics application, where I need to fetch some data on per hour basis of a particular month. for example I wanna get the data from jun 01 2012 to jun 30 2012 and I need to fetch the data of every hour between those days.
Like 12:00 13:00,13:00-14:00 ....etc.

How do I do it. Kindly let me know. Using 1.8.7 platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Rails there is a Date method `step`: http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#M001273

---

On pure ruby just write simple loop:

```
t=Time.new(2012,01,01,0,0,0) #start time
max_time=Time.new(2012,01,31,23,59,59) #end time
step=60*60 #1hour
while t<=max_time
     p t #your code here
     t += step
end
```

To simplify use this ruby extension:

```
module TimeStep

  def step(limit, step)  # :yield: time
    t = self
    op = [:-,:<=,:>=][step<=>0]
    while t.__send__(op, limit)
       yield t
       t += step
    end
    self
  end
end

Time.send(:include, TimeStep) #include the extension
```

Usage:

```
t=Time.new(2012,01,01,0,0,0)
t.step(Time.new(2012,01,31,23,59,59),3600) do |time|
  puts time
end
```

You can also down-iterate:

```
t=Time.new(2012,01,31)
t.step(Time.new(2012,01,1),-3600) do |time|
   puts time
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
start = Date.new(2012, 6, 1).to_time.to_i
stop  = Date.new(2012, 6, 30).to_time.to_i

(start..stop).step(1.hour).each do |timestamp| 
  puts Time.at(timestamp)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is already an answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/501291/1205299).

Answer (score 0):

Yup, step is fine!

```
a = Time.now
b = Time.now + 3600*8
(a..b).step(3600){|t| puts t}
```