# What is a clean and idiomatic way to insert missing minutes in an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, iterator

Consider an array of datetimes:

```
2010-07-17 16:09:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:10:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:12:00 -0700
2010-07-17 17:44:00 -0700
2010-07-18 02:12:00 -0700
```

What is a clean and idiomatic way to iterate over the array and insert missing minutes, so that the output is:

```
2010-07-17 16:09:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:10:00 -0700
2012-07-17 16:11:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:12:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:13:00 -0700
...
```

Ruby 1.9.3

EDIT: More info:

It is actually an array of hashes, with datetimes as the key:

```
2010-07-17 16:09:00 -0700 => 5
2010-07-17 16:10:00 -0700 => 22
2010-07-17 16:12:00 -0700 => 3
```

So, each missing minute should have the value of the previous existing minute.

Also, not using Rails.

Comment: The whole premise of this question is preposterous. If you want an array of DateTimes one minute apart, why does it matter what you start with?

Comment: Just regenerate the whole array using a loop a like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501253/iterate-over-ruby-time-object-with-delta

Comment: What do you want to set the key as for missing datetimes?

Comment: The value for a missing minute should be value for the previous minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'

# dummy dates
dates = "2010-07-17 16:09:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:10:00 -0700
2010-07-17 16:12:00 -0700
2010-07-17 17:44:00 -0700
2010-07-18 02:12:00 -0700"

datetimes = dates.lines.map{|s| DateTime.parse(s) }

continuous_datetimes = [datetimes.min]

while continuous_datetimes.last < datetimes.max
  continuous_datetimes.push( continuous_datetimes.last + 1.0/24.0/60.0 )
end

continuous_datetimes.first(10).each{|d| puts d}
# 2010-07-17T16:09:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:10:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:11:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:12:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:13:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:14:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:15:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:16:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:17:00-07:00
# 2010-07-17T16:18:00-07:00
```

---

### EDIT

the following code reflects your hash structure.

Setup:

```
require 'date'

# dummy dates
hash = {
  DateTime.parse("2010-07-17 16:09:00 -0700") => 5,
  DateTime.parse("2010-07-17 16:10:00 -0700") => 22,
  DateTime.parse("2010-07-17 16:12:00 -0700") => 3
}
```

Actual code:

```
new_hash = hash.inject(Hash[ *hash.first ]) do |tmp,kv|
  while tmp.keys.last < kv.first
    tmp[ tmp.keys.last + 1.0/24.0/60.0 ] = kv.last
  end
  tmp
end
```

Output:

```
new_hash.each {|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
# 2010-07-17T16:09:00-07:00 => 5
# 2010-07-17T16:10:00-07:00 => 22
# 2010-07-17T16:11:00-07:00 => 3
# 2010-07-17T16:12:00-07:00 => 3
```

Comment: I don't want to install rails because it would greatly increase the overhead and time to run tests.

Comment: Well, you don't have to :-). Besides, active support's `1.minute` would not work here, so never mind. (i deleted my comment in order not to mislead others reading this post)